# Test python function

Tags: python, testing, assert

Good morning! I need to create a test for a python function. The result to be tested is a very large dataframe in json format. What can I put in assert to test that the json file has been created correctly? Thank you

```
def function (param):
   ...
   ...
assert ()
```

Comment: Shorten version of the large dataset? The idea of testing is to ensure that function works properly and is able to handle errors in case of facing them. So, try to feed function several tiny variants of real data.

Comment: You could write a function that validates the structure (call it *validator*) and which returns True or False appropriately. Then: *assert validator(df)* where *df* is a reference to the structure to be validated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi depends on the test you are searching for.

##### Approach I (functional)

The returned json have a structure, so you can verify for example that the number of columns are correct, the number of rows are correct and so on:

```
jdf = DataFrame({'A':[1,2], 'B':[3,4]}).to_json()
assert len(json.loads(jdf)) ==2
assert set(json.loads(jdf).keys()) == {'A','B'}
```

##### Approach II (non regression)

If you have a previous verified df stored elsewhere you can check that all values are as expected using the [assert_frame_equal](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html#pandas-testing-assert-frame-equal)